# Access 'Chrome Web Store API' from a Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, chrome-web-store

I would like to access the 'Chrome Web Store API' from a Cloud Function.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index#Licenses

Why?
We are making a chrome extension, and would like to check to see if a user has purchased the extension (i.e. license) in the web store. The license information is available from the Chrome Web Store API. We could make the request to the Web Store API directly from the extension, but then there is a (uglyish) pop-up for the user requesting permission to access the API on their behalf, which isn't ideal. We want to instead make a Cloud Function endpoint, that when sent the userID, responds with true or a false, depending on whether the user has a valid license. The Cloud Function should be able to get the license data for any user on this URL: (https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/licenses/$appID/$userID).

I have tried digging around for examples on how to do this. I think I need the equivalent of the Cloud Function version of the Google API Client Library, that handles authentication via oath2 or a service account.. but even then I don't see a way to set the URL for a GET request.

Much appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Comment: You should _not_ be needing to rely on user authorizing the request. Have you looked at https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to follow the instructions to the letter, including adding the relevant permissions, oath2 scopes and client id, to manifest.json. Our oath2 section has '../auth/chromewebstore.readonly', although one example in the link also has '../auth/plus.login', I could try adding that. The user still gets an uglyish popup to confirm their account, I guess this is a side effect of chrome.identity.getAuthToken(). Our other plan was to use chrome.identity.id, send that to a cloud function API, which then checks the Web Store API itself, on behalf of the project owner, not the user.